# Google pie chart not displayed on echo

Tags: php, html, pie-chart

I am trying to create pie chart that displayed based on mysql data. But why did my Google pie chart isnt displayed when I added `<?php while ($s=$done->fetch()) {echo $s['count(*)'];} ?>`? If I dont add it, the pie chart just display it perfectly.

I have try googling it but seems like I couldnt find the solution. Thankyou in advance!

```html
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname:coits','root','');

$done = $db->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM coi_system WHERE month(todays_date) = EXTRACT(month FROM (NOW())) 
AND year(todays_date) = EXTRACT(year FROM (NOW())) 
AND CHAR_LENGTH(department)>0');
$notdone = $db->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM coi_system WHERE month(todays_date) = EXTRACT(month FROM (NOW())) 
AND year(todays_date) = EXTRACT(year FROM (NOW())) 
AND CHAR_LENGTH(department)<1');

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Updated',     <?php while ($s=$done->fetch()) {echo $s['count(*)'];} ?>],
          ['Not updated', <?php while ($s=$notdone->fetch()) {echo $s['count(*)'];} ?>]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
    
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  color: #18786E;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav a {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-style: outset;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  color: black;
}

.btn_logout {
  background-color: #18786E;
  color: #e9e9e9;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: 12px 20px;
}

.nav{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-width:1px 0;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #137D72;
}
.nav li{
    display:inline;
}
.nav a{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px;
    color: #FAFBFB;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav">
      <img src="HICOM LOGO.png" style="width:130px ;height:80px; margin-left: 30px;"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
      <label style="font-size: 36px; margin-bottom: 8px;">Cost Optimisation Initiatives System</label>
      <form style="margin-left: auto;" method="post" action="logout.php">
      <button class="btn_logout" id="submit" type="submit" >LogOut</button></form>
  </div>

<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="admin_search.php">Update</a></li>
  <li><a href="report_admin.php">Report</a></li>
</ul>

<br><br>

<div align="center">
<div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Check your browser's console, there's probably a syntax error which most likely stems from the fact there's no `"count(*)"` column in your `SELECT` clause. The error would be apparent if you viewed your rendered page's source

Comment: @Phil I have checked the browser's console theres no syntax error. I also has added `COUNT(*)` in my select clause but still no change. Why is it?